# How to exclude packages in spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark based streaming application which I run on AWS EMR using spark-submit command from the commandline. I include some dependencies by using --packages option of spark-submit. However, I also want to exclude one dependency when spark-submit resolves dependencies. For this I tried to use --exclude-packages option of spark-submit but having issues with it. The error I am seeing with actual application is same as the one that below command produces (also running on AWS EMR):

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 1024m --executor-memory 1024m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.3.2 --exclude-packages com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.7.3  /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.2.jar 10
```

The error I see is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Provided Maven Coordinates must be in the form 'groupId:artifactId:version'. The coordinate provided is: com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.7.3:*
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$$anonfun$extractMavenCoordinates$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$$anonfun$extractMavenCoordinates$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:1013)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.extractMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1013)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.createExclusion(SparkSubmit.scala:1324)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$$anonfun$resolveMavenCoordinates$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:1298)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$$anonfun$resolveMavenCoordinates$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:1297)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1297)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doPrepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:171)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I do think I am giving the Maven coordinates for amazon-kinesis-client correctly because, first, it looks correct to me, and second, if I remove --exclude-packages from my command and add Maven coordinates of amazon-kinesis-client as it is to --packages option, the command runs fine, see below command which runs fine:

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 1024m --executor-memory 1024m --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.2,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.3.2,com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client:1.7.3 /usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.3.2.jar 10
```

So I am not sure what I am doing wrong when using --exclude-packages option. Is this could be a bug in spark-submit? Has anyone run into this issue before?

P.S. I did do a search in JIRA for Spark project for any open/closed issues related to above issue but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Use `--exclude-packages com.amazonaws:amazon-kinesis-client` with no version defined.